# Show WooCommerce custom checkout fields using a WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I use a plugin to create some custom B2B fields. Now I need these custom made fields to be shown at the checkout page.

```
function add_custom_b2b_fields_checkout( $fields ){

  $args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'afreg_fields',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'      => '99',
    'orderby'             => 'name',
  );

  $get_b2b_fields = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ($get_b2b_fields->have_posts()) : while ($get_b2b_fields->have_posts()) : $get_b2b_fields->the_post();
    $fields['billing'][$get_b2b_fields->post_name] = array(
        'type'              => 'text',
        'label'             => get_the_title(),
        'placeholder'       => __(" ", "woocommerce"),
        'class'             => array('b2b-field'),
        'required'          => false,
    );
    endwhile;
    return $fields;
  endif;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_custom_b2b_fields_checkout' );
```

The code works nice almost. But it shows only the last field, as if the `while` run correctly but the `return $fields` shows only the first custom field instead of all of them.

How can I show all the fields instead of just one? I tried adding a `.=` at the `$fields` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little mistake in your code as `$get_b2b_fields->post_name` is empty.

Simply replace:

```
$fields['billing'][$get_b2b_fields->post_name] = array(
```

with:

```
$fields['billing'][$get_b2b_fields->post->post_name] = array(
```

Now it will work.

Comment: You rock! I would never imagine I had to use another `->post` in there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_custom_b2b_fields_checkout' );
```

change it to

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_custom_b2b_fields_checkout' );
```

and add `do_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields');` on the page where you want to show